# How to use markers as keys in a hash map?

Tags: hash-tables, equality, marker

I'm creating a hash map and I'd like to use markers as keys. I set the hash map equality test to "equal", but the last line from the below code is returning ("bye" "fly") instead of ("bazooka" "joe"). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```lisp
(let* ((tmp (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
       (marker-1 (make-marker))
       (marker-2 (make-marker)))
  (set-marker marker-1 1)
  (set-marker marker-2 1)
  (message "markers equal 1?: %s" (equal marker-1 marker-2))
  (message "markerp 1: %s, 2: %s" (markerp marker-1) (markerp marker-2))
  (puthash marker-1 (list "hi") tmp)
  (puthash marker-2 (list "bye" "fly") tmp)
  (message "markers equal 2?: %s" (equal marker-1 marker-2))
  (puthash marker-1 (list "bazooka" "joe") tmp)
  (gethash marker-2 tmp))
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, to me. The doc says that if the objects are `equal` then their `sxhash-equal` values are the same. But in this case the markers are `equal` and they have different `sxhash-equal` values. If someone doesn't provide a good answer here, consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: From [(elisp) Defining Hash](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Hash.html): " If two objects OBJ1 and OBJ2 are ‘equal’, then ‘(sxhash-equal OBJ1)’ and ‘(sxhash-equal OBJ2)’ are the same integer." But that doesn't seem to be true here.

Comment: @Drew Indeed, looking briefly at the source code of 27.2, `sxhash` has a comment about `Lisp_Vectorlike` objects “Others are `equal' if they are `eq'”, but that doesn't match with `internal_equal` which several extra cases with comparisons by value: markers, overlays and window configurations.

Comment: Note that using markers as keys in a hash table with equality by value is fragile: it can only work if the markers' positions don't change throughout the lifetime of the hash table. So you need to make sure the hash table isn't kept around past a call to `set-marker` or a modification of the buffers or other things that can change the markers' positions.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': Yes, your last comment is a good one. (But I assume the OP was giving a test case, just to ask about the `equal` test when they do have the same position.)

Comment: Thanks everyone. For now, I will just use position instead of marker, and consider filing a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [reported this problem](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2022-05/msg00051.html) to `emacs-devel@gnu.org`.

@Stefan Monnier [replied](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2022-05/msg00052.html) that this seems to be fixed in the development version (master) for Emacs 29.